# Cypress-cucumber-preprocessor missing steps in execution

Tags: cypress, false-positive, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

When I execute the tests many steps of the scenario are missing and it the tests "pass", although these steps were never executed, they are not displayed in test runner.

It is a sporadic issue, but decreases the reliability of the tests, since these were not executed but in macro, it looks like passed tests.

Has anyone run into the same problem?